# Blazorise DataGridNumericColumn DisplayFormat does not seem to work

Tags: c#, web, blazorise

I am using Blazorise to develop a Job Management System. Using the DataGrid and DataGridNumericColumns does not display my numbers correctly. I want the Decimal(18,4) Numbers to display as follows:

123 456 789.1234 (1.00)

but I get

1,0000

I have tried to use the DisplayFormat property but I cannot get it to work.

DisplayFormat="n2" shows n2 and not the number.

The Blazorise Documentation does not really help in this case.

n.b. I am new to c# and Blazor. I am a Delphi and php programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `DisplayFormat="{0:n2}"`. You can see in the [Blazorise Documentation](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/binding-data/in-memory) how `DisplayFormat` is being use for the salary column.

```
<DataGridColumn Field="@nameof(Employee.Salary)" Caption="Salary" DisplayFormat="{0:C}" ... />
```